How to get only keys as autocomplete from a interface?
How to get only keys as autocomplete from a interface ?
interface IUser {
  id: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}

€:
I have here an array and want to add my keys in there:
  let allowedSortIds = [
    'id', 
    'firstname', 
    'lastname',
  ]


type keys = keyof IUser;? It's not clear what "autocomplete" you're referring to though.

@zerkms I edited my code above

You cannot have a value with keys: typescript interfaces are erased from runtime.

Are you saying you want your IDE to autosuggest elements to add to allowedSortIds? If so then maybe you want to annotate it as (keyof IUser)[] as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz yes thanks!

If you want allowedSortIds to be an array that only accepts values which are keys of the IUser interface, then you can annotate it as Array<keyof IUser> or the equivalent (keyof IUser)[], using the keyof type operator to query IUser for the union of the literal types of its keys.  Once TypeScript knows that the elements of allowedSortIds can only be keyof IUser, then IntelliSense will auto-suggest and auto-complete these types for you also:
let allowedSortIds: (keyof IUser)[] = [
    //  ^
    //  "firstname"
    //  "id"
    //  "lastname"
]

Playground link to code
